# Replace all values of matrix where another matrix is false (0)

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have matrix `A` and `B`. I want to set all values in `A` to `0`, where `B` is `false` (has `0` as value). How  can I do this the best way?

A and B have the same size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Boolean operator, assuming A and B are of same sizes, but they don't have to be of same datatype

```
A(~B) = 0
```

More info [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html).

Answer (score 3):

find all indices of `B` with `0` and set those indices in `A` as `0`

```
>>A(B == 0) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what is exactly happening you can use this as well

```
size=size(im);

for x=1:size(1)
    for y=1:size(2)
        if B(x,y)==0;
            A(x,y)=0;
        end
    end
end
```